# Different dimens.xml for different screens

Tags: android

I have to provide two different font sizes for two different types of devices. The first group are smaller devices (e.g. the Nexus S, or devices with around 480px height) and the second group are all other phones (e.g. Galaxy Nexus, Nexus 4, 5 and so on). I already supported tablets.

By now I created a `values-sw320dp` folder with a `dimens.xml` in it - for smaller devices to use, and there is also the default values folder with their `dimens.xml` in it, to support all other phones.

The problem is that the `dimens.xml` from the `sw320dp` folder is applied everywhere. 
Am I supposed to create a `values-sw340dp` or `values-sw360dp` folder for those devices? What is the purpose of the `dimens.xml` in the default `values` folder if I am going to bucket devices by their smallest width? How does a device put itself in a density bucket, look for their closest `sw-dp` folder or what?

I know that this question has been asked a thousand times before, but I really could not google it out or find it on SO.

Answer (score 1):

The Nexus S is a common **hdpi** device (240 dpi), with a resolution of 480x800 pixels.
Therefore, you can use the `values-hdpi` for storing that device's `dimens .xml`.

You might consider to support smaller devices such as **mdpi** or **ldpi** ones, as well.
And "not so smaller" devices too (i.e.: **xhdpi** and **xxhdpi**).

Comment: Shouldn't I use the new **sw** qualifiers instead of density identifiers? They were introduced like ages ago.

Comment: They work just fine. The sw qualifiers are useful for **tablets**, because these ones use higher resolutions, but at lower densities (often **mdpi** or **hdpi**).

Comment: So is there a way to support only hdpi devices with a `values-hdpi` folder, and use the default `values` folder to support all other phones? Or I'm supposed to make as many `values` folders as there are density buckets?

Comment: Well, you are supposed to make as many buckets as many densities **you want** to support. Or, at least, **if there are differences** (by using **dp**s and **sp**s and **9 patches** or **svg**s, you're quite safe) between a density an another one. Keep in mind that the default density is **mdpi** (normalized to 160 dpi). On phones, this had usually an associated resolution of 320x480 px.

Comment: Before talking, read this [official document](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of qualifiers (IMHO), ones are responsible for density and the others are more about screen sizes, and there are some identifiers for tablets. It is not only having a single suffix like hdpi for folder, you can play with couple of them.

You can find more info on the Official website:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html